# Page source in CefSharp changes even after IsLoading is false

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I'm using CefSharp to load an Amazon product page and look for some elements in the resulting source.  I'm running into a problem where the source of the page seems to be changing.  Here's my code:

```
private IWebBrowser browser;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("http://google.com");
    this.Controls.Add(browser as ChromiumWebBrowser);

    browser.Load("https://www.amazon.com/dp/B004S8F7QM");
    while (browser.IsLoading)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(50);
    }
    string htmlSource = browser.GetSourceAsync().Result;

    // Look for elements in htmlSource
}
```

Now when I look for an HTML element in `htmlSource` that I know is present on the page because I looked at the source with my normal browser, that element's text doesn't exist in `htmlSource`.

However, if I add a long enough delay after `browser.IsLoading` becomes false, then that HTML element **does** appear in my source.

```
browser.Load("https://www.amazon.com/dp/B004S8F7QM");
while (browser.IsLoading)
{
    Thread.Sleep(50);
}
Thread.Sleep(1000);     // Additional delay
string htmlSource = browser.GetSourceAsync().Result;
```

What is causing this, and how can I tell when the page is completely finished loading so that I can search the source for HTML elements?

Comment: Many pages dynamically load content after the page has loaded (resources have loaded and the DOM is ready). What you are seeing is expected.  There's unlikely a one size fits all solution as the definition of fully loaded differs between pages, some never stop loading content. What html element needs to be present for the page to be considered loaded?

Comment: @amaitland I was afraid that would be the case.  The difficulty is that my program is checking for the presence or absence or a particular HTML element, so I can't just wait until that element shows up because it might legitimately not be on the page.  I guess I'll just keep a 2-3 second delay in there.  Or maybe I'll find a dynamically loaded element that will always be on the page, and then wait for that element to load before I check for the element I'm interested in.  Thanks for your help.